# On one server 2 databases have the same model and Context

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I have the following question

First, I have an Sql Server (MyServer), where I have two different databases (databaseOne, databaseTwo).

Then, I'm working in a ASP.NET MVC 4 project, and this is what I want to do:
**I want to create my Model with all the tables from databaseOne, but also add in the same model all the tables from databaseTwo.**

All I want is all my tables in the same context because I need to do several joins between databaseOne and databaseTwo. How can I accomplish this?

I have already created my Model for databaseOne, but how can I add all the tables from databaseTwo?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to create views in db1 which make the joins between db1's own tables and the tables required in db2. You can then get the views in the model.

To update the tables in db2 I don't think is possible, but you can certainly read them via views in db1.